# Edit the source of a page in Opera

Tags: windows-7, opera

How can I edit source of a page in Opera? I used to be able to do so simply right-clicking the page, selecting "Source", edit the page and applying changes. Now, after selecting "Source", it doesn't look like I can edit the page. The [help page](http://help.opera.com/Windows/12.10/en/sourceview.html) didn't help.

I use Opera 31.0.1889.174 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **DevTools**

Opera now uses Blink/Chromium so it has [Chromium's DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/).

> The Chrome Developer Tools (DevTools for short), are a set of web authoring and debugging tools built into Google Chrome [or your Chromium based browser]. The DevTools provide web developers deep access into the internals of the browser and their web application. Use the DevTools to efficiently track down layout issues, set JavaScript breakpoints, and get insights for code optimization.

### Firebug Lite

If you are familiar with Firefox and Firebug, perhaps you could try [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

> - Compatible with all major browsers: IE6+, Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome
> - Same look and feel as Firebug
> - Inspect HTML and modify style in real-time
> - Powerful console logging functions
> - Rich representation of DOM elements
>   Extend Firebug Lite and add features to make it even more powerful

Comment: Thanks, works good. Very similar to Chrome Developer Tools (maybe Dragonfly is also based on Webkit Web Inspector?)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Yeah, they're all similar. Most browser developer tools were probably based on WebKit WebInspector.

Comment: Dragonfly _was_ the web developer tool for the old Opera (Presto, up to version 12.x). The OP says he uses the current Opera (Blink, from version 15 on), although the help link was for Presto. Opera Blink doesn't have Dragonfly; it uses the _same_ (not just similar) inspector Chrome and other Blink-based variants do, which is launched instead of Dragonfly when you "inspect element". You can edit code directly from that inspector, and it will apply changes directly to the DOM, but you can no longer edit/apply from viewing source as you could in Opera Presto.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter I see, thanks for the information. Does the new version of the tools have a name?